# Redirect domainname.com to sites.google.com

Tags: redirects, google-workspace

I have a `domainname.com` and want to redirect it to Google Apps, `sites.google.com` or iGoogle via the CNAME.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Who is your domain registrar?

Answer (score 1):

Try following the instructions on this link:
http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47283

Comment: I believe this is the correct link - http://sites.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99448

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could redirect a domain name to another domain name.

One ways is to use your domain manager dashboard. If you have GoDaddy just log in there and click on set up DNS.

Other way is via [htaccess](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php).

There are more other ways.

Answer (score 0):

[Google sites has a help document](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/99448) that answers this question for you.

The basic steps are:

- Tell Google Sites about your domain name.  There are a different set of instructions for this depending on your sites is powered by Google Apps or not.
- Use your domain registrar or DNS host to set a CNAME record pointing to `ghs.google.com`.   The ability to do this is generally found in the "Domain Management" or "Advanced Settings".